# how to fix telegram source code runing error

Tags: java, android, telegram

i change my telegram package name and i get this error every time i run app:

> Trying to load lib
>   /data/data/ir.amatis.vistagram/files/lib/libtmessages.22loc.so
>   0x4189a530 03-06 13:22:21.059 32240-32240/? D/dalvikvm: Shared lib
>   '/data/data/ir.amatis.vistagram/files/lib/libtmessages.22loc.so'
>   already loaded in same CL 0x4189a530 03-06 13:22:21.069 32240-32240/?
>   W/dalvikvm: No implementation found for native
>   Lir/amatis/tgnet/ConnectionsManager;.native_setJava:(Z)V 03-06
>   13:22:21.069 32240-32240/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 03-06
>   13:22:21.069 32240-32240/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x415f18b0) 03-06 13:22:21.069 32240-32240/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
>   ir.amatis.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava:(Z)V
>                                                          at ir.amatis.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(Native Method)
>                                                          at ir.amatis.vistagram.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:322)

this is lib folder pic:
[image: lib folder android sudio]

[image: another image from package path]

Comment: post your code here

Comment: this is telegram source code i only change package names

Comment: the problem is this line : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: ir.amatis.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava:(Z)V
ir.amatis.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(Native Method)

Comment: Where do you fire this code?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`libtmessages.22loc.so` not found means

> Incorrect path that you setup and/or wrong build.

But if you app already launched successfully you have to check your path. Package Name in most cases means path.

Comment: how can i setup path ?